# iOS: Codesign error: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable in subcomponent Base.lproj

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, codesign

I have a project that was building just fine. Seemingly randomly, doing a Run one time resulted in a codesign error that I've been unable to resolve for 2 days.

The error reads:

*bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
In subcomponent: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Base.lproj*

I'm not sure why this error sprung up. It may have happened after I selected a 'Team' in Xcode - but I can't remember (and I don't know why that would cause an issue). I tried cleaning up my Keychain, creating the bundle identifier in my developer account, a handful of Terminal commands from other posts, to no avail.

What's odd to me is that it seems to indicate it has something to do with Base.lproj - which holds only the LaunchScreen nib and my Main.storyboard. Could there be something in Storyboard that is causing a codesign issue? Something else? SOS.

Answer (score 14):

This is a big stab in the dark, but I got this error when I added a directory named "resources". Removing it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Can confirm: had a number of weird signing errors (including the above) until I renamed my 'Resources' directory to something else…

Comment: Changing Resources from a Folder Reference to a Group in the Xcode project fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue with Xcode 7.3.1 and cocoapods. I ended up doing the following:

1.Closed Xcode

2.Removed everything under my DerivedData folder

rm -fr /Users/{user}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*

3.Restarted Xcode and rebuilt the project

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me. Somehow, when I opened XCode Beta, building in the normal XCode stopped working. Removing the Derived Data folder put an end to my 2 days of pain

Comment: This is my first answer on Stackoverflow and I am glad that I could help out someone.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I added the script fixing a keychain error -34018 which first had appeared in XCode 6.3.

```
#!/bin/sh
codesign --verify --force --sign "$CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY" 
"$CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CocoaPods, then update CocoaPods and then all the pods worked from me.

`sudo gem update cocoapods` followed by `pod install`